# Another matrix diagonalization problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrices $X$ and $Y$ in $[0,1]^{n\times m}$, for $n > m > 3$, so that $X1_m=1_m$ and $Y1_m=1_m$, where $1_m$ denotes a $m$-length column vector of ones, find a matrix $Q$ in $R^{m\times m}$ so that $C(X,Y)=Q^TX^TYQ$ satisfies the following tree conditions:

$i$) $C(X,X)$ is diagonal with diagonal elements given by the the sum of rows of $X$

$ii$) The sum of the columns of $C(X,Y)$ equals the sum of rows of $X$

$iii$) The sum of the rows of $C(X,Y)$ equals the sum of rows of $Y$

What can be said about the uniqueness of the matrix $Q$?

Comment: Why is this problem interesting? It seems like an arbitrary list of conditions to me.

Comment: Small typo.... the dimension of the input and output of X are the same but that doesn't jive with the nxm shape of X.

More importantly I can't figure out what the properties of Q are supposed to be

Comment: Since X and Y do not exist (as n > m), we can take Q to be the matrix of all zeros.  Gerhard "One As Good As Another" Paseman, 2012.05.05

Comment: Why is the problem interesting? Its solution will have relevance in land cover change detection. Each row of $X$ and $Y$ represents membership vectors of $m$ land cover types. If $X,Y\in\{1,0\}^{n\times m}$, i.e., are binary matrices with exactly one non-zero element per row, then $C=X^TY$ quantifies the changes among land cover types, and $C$ satisfies all three conditions above ($Q=I$). The problem arises when $X,Y\in[1,0]^{n\times m}$, that is partial memberships are allowed.

Comment: BTW, could not figure out the typo.

Comment: Regarding the properties of $Q$, consider this. Let $\Lambda_x = \mathrm{diag}(1_n^T X)$ and $\Lambda_y = \mathrm{diag}(1_n^T Y)$be the diagonal matrices formed with the row sum of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Then, from ii) and iii), one can get $C 1_m = \Lambda_x 1_m$ and  $1_m^TC = 1_m^T\Lambda_y$, for $C=Q^TX^TY^TQ$. These equations imply that the vector $1_m$ is a right eigenvector of $C$ with respect to $\Lambda_x$ and a left eigenvector with respecto to $\Lambda_y$.

Comment: At the very least, you need X1_m = 1_n, although it is unclear if you are talking about a vector of all ones or not.  Also, you might drop the hat versions of X and Y and express the problem using X, Y, and Q and not X hat or Y hat.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.05.07

Comment: In condition *i)*, don't you mean for the diagonal entries of $C(X,X)$ to be the sums of the *columns* of $X$, not the rows?  Also, the typo that David Benson-Putnins mentioned occurs in $X1_m = Y1_m = 1_m$.  It should be $X1_m = Y1_m = 1_n$ -- your matrices $X$ and $Y$ have $n$ rows and $m$ columns.